# Emacs M-h selects paragraph + an extra line

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, when I type `M-h` (`mark-paragraph`), Emacs selects the paragraph under point plus an extra line (typically right above the paragraph). Is there a way to ask Emacs to just select the paragraph?

**Note:** I have noticed this behavior under `shell-script-mode`, but haven't checked if it occurs with other major modes.

Answer (score 1):

It's just how Emacs tells paragraphs apart.  I wouldn't argue with it.  This way, if you keep pressing M-{, more paragraphs get marked seemlessly.  And if you really wanted to shrink by one line, just C-n.

I don't mean to be rude, but having started with Emacs from a Windows background, I wasted a lot of time trying to get it to work *exactly* how I wanted.  CUA, delete-selection, etc, etc.  I learned a lot but also wasted a lot of time.

Now I run Emacs with most of that stuff disabled, and I actually find the "Emacs paradigm" works.  Most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a Vim user and at the begining I wanted a similar behavior, but thinking a little bit more I noticed that the way Emacs does is more logical, imagine this situation: You want to delete a paragraph between two more paragraphs, if you just select the lines with no extra line, you will end up with two empty lines between the reminder paragraphs.

Even then I have a function that selects just the paragraph with no extra line:

```
;; mark just the paragraph
(defun dg-mark-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (mark-paragraph)
  (goto-char (region-beginning))
  (when (= (string-match paragraph-separate (thing-at-point 'line)) 0)
    (forward-line)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-8") 'dg-mark-paragraph)
```